# Are shared beans between prototype beans threadsafe?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a `prototype` bean, which i'm using in a multi-threaded application. I'm using an `ThreadPoolExecutionService` to run the different instances of the `prototype`.

I want to gather some statistics on the code that the threads are running, which includes creating several variables, and incrementing them as the prototypes are run.

I've though about creating a `singleton` bean, and injecting the bean into the `prototype`, then calling a method to set the statistics.

Some dummy code to illustrate the point: credit to [mykong](http://www.mkyong.com) for the dummy code, which i've modified slightly.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

    PrintThread printThread1 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
    printThread1.setName("Thread 1");

    PrintThread printThread2 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
    printThread2.setName("Thread 2");

    PrintThread printThread3 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
    printThread3.setName("Thread 3");

    PrintThread printThread4 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
    printThread4.setName("Thread 4");

    PrintThread printThread5 = (PrintThread) ctx.getBean("printThread");
    printThread5.setName("Thread 5");

    printThread1.start();
    printThread2.start();
    printThread3.start();
    printThread4.start();
    printThread5.start();

}
```

The printThread, with injection:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class PrintThread extends Thread{

@Inject
private StatGatherer statGatherer;

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(getName() + " is running");

    //is this threadsafe?   
    statGatherer.writeSomeStat(); 

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(getName() + " is running");
}

}
```

Edit: Example of threadsafe stats class. The code contains three maps, which can be incremented via synchronized methods.

```
@Component("statistics")
public class StatGathererImpl implements StatGatherer {

private ConcurrentHashMap<Character, Integer> mappingType = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<Character, Integer> mappingGroup = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ConcurrentHashMap<Character, Integer> mappingDirection = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public synchronized void incrementMappingType(char mapType) {
    if(mappingType.keySet().contains(mapType)){
        mappingType.replace(mapType, mappingType.get(mapType), mappingType.get(mapType)+1);
    }else{
        mappingType.put(mapType, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void incrementMappingGroup(char mapGroup) {
    if(mappingGroup.keySet().contains(mapGroup)){
        mappingGroup.replace(mapGroup, mappingGroup.get(mapGroup), mappingGroup.get(mapGroup)+1);
    }else{
        mappingGroup.put(mapGroup, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void incrementMappingDirection(char mapDirection) {
    if(mappingDirection.keySet().contains(mapDirection)){
        mappingDirection.replace(mapDirection, mappingDirection.get(mapDirection), mappingDirection.get(mapDirection)+1);
    }else{
        mappingDirection.put(mapDirection, 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As long as the code in `writeSomeStat()` is threadsafe, this works. We do something like that with metrics beans which encapsulate a metrics library. That works flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you would do about making the method threadsafe?

Comment: @Sam it's not possible to answer this question without any code. Thread safety is a wide area.

Comment: @JEY I'll add some basic code for the threadsafe class.